# No duplication work in two instance of simple job processor

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, batch-processing, jobs, job-scheduling

I have a web app (Asp.net Core 2.0) and a simple job processor (.NET Core 2.0) as below.

My web app will add jobs to a database, the processor will get the job every 5 minutes and do some logic.

I wrapped the processor in docker, deployed & run on two servers (there are two instances)

Any solutions to make sure there is no duplicate work here? I want two instances active at the same time.

**Simple job processor**

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Background worker is running");

    //Query job from table job  

    if (DateTime.UtcNow < job.ExpiredAt)
    {
        //Call external REST API

        //Do something
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Background worker is delayed for 5 minutes\r\n");
    Task.Delay(JobInterval * 60 * 1000).Wait();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something to coordinate your workers. You can't just have multiple instances grabbing at the same pool and keep things separate with no duplication of work. Concurrency will eat your lunch. Instead, there should be a coordinating node that assigns tasks out to the other nodes. That's the only way you can handle this.

Comment: I'm thinking about adding another table for checking the active job processor and the inactive one will do nothing. if the active processor is not working for a while, the other will be up. Is that Ok?

Comment: About your solution, could you give me an example or stuffs about how to implement it in .NET Core?

Comment: There's no one way. In general, this would essentially be a service hub or message queue. Azure has an out of the box solution. You could also use something like RabbitMQ, though. Personally, I'd take the more expedient route and just use an existing job processing solution like Hangfire. No need to reinvent the wheel.